# Javascript: how to pass parameters to function dynamically

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

I'm trying to figure out a way to pass parameters to a function separated by comma, not an object. I know how to accomplish this like so:

```
var executeCallback = function executeCallback (callback) {
    var args = [];
    if ( typeof opts[callback] === 'function') {
        Array.prototype.push.apply( args, arguments );
        if ( arguments.length > 1 ) { args.shift(); }
            // Opts: a variable from outside this function
            opts[callback](args);
        }
    };

executeCallback('fooCallback', [1, 2, 3], 'bar');
```

But I would really like to pass the args to my  opts object as I would normally, for example:

```
opts[callback](arg1, arg2);
```

Why? Because this way it is easier to use it from the callback function, in my personal preference.

Is there a way to do this dinamically?

Much obliged.

Comment: So you already know about `apply`, that's what you need.

Comment: @elclanrs Nice, can you give me an example?

Comment: `opts[callback].apply(this,args)`

Comment: or you can use
    `opts[callback].call(this, arg1, arg2);`

Comment: @JawwadAlam Not a very scalable/dynamic solution. What if the number of arguments is variable? This is exactly what `apply` is for

Comment: @Ian: Yes, apply is the best choice here, but provided this option as he prefers to call it this way

Comment: @Ian That's precisely the case: the number of passed args is variable.

Comment: @darksoulsong Okay, well then use the comment from above: `opts[callback].apply(this,args)`

Comment: @JawwadAlam not really. But i think I wasn't clear enough  when I mentioned my preference.  I was referring to the way I get the arguments from the callback function, like: callback: function callback (arg1, arg2) {...}, instead of callback: function callback (args) { var arg1 = args.arg1, arg2 = args.arg2; }; Anyway, both ways answer my question. Someone go ahead and post an answer, I'll upvote. Thanks a lot.